# How to create a surveillance system using an IP camera?

Tags: pi-4, raspicam

I am completely new to this whole Raspberry Pi thing, but I would like to create a surveillance system with an IP camera. I have a Dahua Technology Model: DH-IPC-HDW1220SP camera that I connected with a DC cable for power and ethernet cable that I used to create like a network with Raspberry Pi.

I would like to have a livestream from the camera to the Raspberry Pi. How would I do this if it is even possible?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: not a Raspberry Pi specific question ... it is a question about using a linux computer to create a surveillance system

Comment: Try opening the ip/port of the camera in vlc